# Python: Can't print on one line

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm having difficulties displaying my results on one line in Python 2.7. My result is supposed to look as follows:

```
looking -> look ing
```

I didn't manage to get rid of the linebreak after the variable "word".

Does anyone have any recommendations on how to do that?

```
    for word in infile:
        items = re.findall('(\w+)(ing|ly|ed|ious|d|ies|ive|es)',word)
        for key in items:
            print
            print word, '->', key[0], key[1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Strip leading or trailing newline characters away:

```
 print word.strip(), '->', key[0], key[1]
```